# How to update variables in ContentView with SheetView function call?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, api, swiftui

I have a code with a sheet view and a normal view. When I press a button within my sheet view I make an API call. This API call then updates some variables which I'm trying to display in my regular view using ´ForEach´. However, when I make the call in the sheet view and close it down, the array does not seem to update in my normal view. My view just remains blank (except for displaying the button that says "Show sheet". How do I make the array update so that it isn't blank?

Here is my regular view:

```
 
// MARK: - Schedule View
struct ScheduleView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    @State private var showingSheet = true

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                ForEach(SheetView().vm.Trips, id: \.self) { dict in
                    Text(dict["Origin"]!) // I want this varible to update, but I doesn't
                    Text(dict["Destination"]!) // It instead remains blank
                }
                Button("Show sheet") {
                    showingSheet.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                    SheetView()
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width*0.7, height: geo.size.height*0.06)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(11)
                .position(x: geo.size.width/2, y: geo.size.height/2)
                // MARK: - Padding funkar inte
                
            }
            
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

And here is my sheet view:

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @StateObject var vm: PlanTripViewModel = PlanTripViewModel()
    @State var selected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {geo in
            ZStack{
                VStack {
                    TextField("From", text: $vm.origin.input).padding()
                    TextField("To", text: $vm.dest.input).padding()
                    TextField("00:00", text: $vm.arrivalTime).padding()
                    TextField("yyyy-mm-dd", text: $vm.travelDate).padding()
    
                    Button("Add trip") {
                        vm.fetchStatus = .start // This starts the API call in another file of mine
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // This closes the sheet view
                    }.padding()
                }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            
 
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you're making a *new* `SheetView` instance on every single `ForEach` call -- it's not the same one that you're using in your `sheet` call.

To solve this, you'll want to store the state in your parent view and give the `sheet` view a reference to it.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @ObservedObject var vm: PlanTripViewModel //<-- Here
    @State var selected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {geo in
            ZStack{
                VStack {
                    TextField("From", text: $vm.origin.input).padding()
                    TextField("To", text: $vm.dest.input).padding()
                    TextField("00:00", text: $vm.arrivalTime).padding()
                    TextField("yyyy-mm-dd", text: $vm.travelDate).padding()
    
                    Button("Add trip") {
                        vm.fetchStatus = .start // This starts the API call in another file of mine
                        presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss() // This closes the sheet view
                    }.padding()
                }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            }
            
 
            
        }
    }
}

struct ScheduleView: View {
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    @State private var showingSheet = true
    @StateObject var vm: PlanTripViewModel //<-- Here

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                ForEach(vm.Trips, id: \.self) { dict in
                    Text(dict["Origin"]!)
                    Text(dict["Destination"]!)
                }
                Button("Show sheet") {
                    showingSheet.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                    SheetView(vm: vm) //<-- Here
                }
                .frame(width: geo.size.width*0.7, height: geo.size.height*0.06)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(11)
                .position(x: geo.size.width/2, y: geo.size.height/2)
                // MARK: - Padding funkar inte
                
            }
            
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

*(Note: you may know this already, but force unwrapping your dictionary values with `!` will cause a crash if the keys don't exist. You may want to use optional binding (`if let`) or another safe check to make sure they exist.)*

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but now my API call is super slow, like 10 times slower than before. Do you know what could be causing that or if there is a way to solve it?

Comment: Nothing in this change should effect the speed of an API call — there’s just one call getting done either way and I didn’t change threads or queues. You also haven’t shown any code for your API call, so it’s not really possible to diagnose. I would need to see a [mre] — probably a good fit for a new question.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I have discovered that the problem was only due to my slow laptop since when I run it on my desktop it works much faster. But I still think it's kinda weird that the speed issue only occurred after the change in the code, but I guess it's no issue :)